# Post Serialized data and Make the insert

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server

I have a form with several radio buttons grouped by the same name, and those radio buttons are generated dinamically, there are 20 in total, but it will only be submitted 4 each time. Each radio button group as an ID as name of the group. When post the form to PHP (using jQuery Serialize) I get something like this:

```
1=3&2=6&4=9&7=2
```

I need to get the values of each parameter, in this case 1, 2, 4 and 7 and also to know which was the fields submitted (in this case the field 1, 2, 4 and 7 was submitted)

I did something like this, but not working:

```
for ($c = 1; $c <= 20; $c++){

if (isset($_GET[$c])){
    $question_id = $c;
    $answer_score = $_GET[$c];
    echo $answer_score;

    $gravar = "INSERT INTO iMood_ColabsQuestionAnswers (colab_id, answer_id, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    /* Set parameter values. */
    $valores = array($user, $question_id, $answer_score);

    echo $valores.'<br />';
    /* Prepare and execute the query. */
    $inserirResposta = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $gravar, $valores);
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($inserirRespota);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
}
```

Can't find a solution for this, because the above solution, doesn't see any record and if use

```
$_GET['$c'];
```

It returns an error in SQL query, saying that found an unexpected `(`.

Comment: `echo $inserirResposta;` to see problem with SQL statement

Comment: First step: look at your SQL query itself and determine where the syntax error is. _Only then_ do you look at your PHP to find out where that error was created in your code. This is breaking your problem down into components, which you should do as a first step in debugging; that you didn't do this renders this question overly broad, in my opinion. SO is a Q&A, not a support site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you submitting that serialized string from jquery?

Doing something like

```
$.ajax(function() {
   data: '1=3&2=6&4=9&7=2'
   ...
});
```

would lead to the problem you're having. This would submit a complete string containing those "query" variables, but do it without an associated field name, so PHP will NOT pick up the fact that this string contains individual key/value pairs.

However, using

```
  data: { data: '1=3&2=6&4=9&7=2' }
```

will let things work in PHP properly, and you'd get at the data like this:

```
$query = parse_str($_GET['data']);

foreach($query as $question_id => $answer_score) {
   ... do database stuff ...
}
```